# How to achieve pagination with BOBJ REST API?

Tags: java, rest, business-intelligence, business-objects

I am trying to show the SAP BusinessObjects/Business Intelligence users in front end grid with pagination using SAP provided RESTful API, but, facing a challenge to find out the total number of pages available or total number of users available.

Also, is there any way to get all available user in single request call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User listing is achieved through query:

```
GET http://<baseURL>/v1/users
```

there is a special parameter which does pagination of the response

> page = < page number >
>
> pagesize = < number >

So you don't need to know the total number of users, but just to adjust that parameter to the number of lines in your grid page and then iterate the call when you change grid page. You query could look smth like this if your grid can hold up to 20 messages:

```
GET http://<baseURL>/v1/users?sort=+name&updated=2020-05-12T20:17:46.384Z,2020-08-12T20:17:46.384Z&page=1&pagesize=20
```

> Also, is there any way to get all available user in single request call?

Passing 1 to `page` and number inherently bigger than total number of users (e.g. 1 000 000) to `pagesize` will give you the thing

Comment: I had already implemented passing higher number as page size as work around (String USER_LIST_URL = "v1/users?page=1&pagesize=100000") and it worked. Looking for any other solution from REST API.